# Dynatree or Fancytree for production?

Tags: dynatree, fancytree

I am looking for a javascript solution which can unordered list to a treeview with checkboxes.

So far the best one I have seen is [Dynatree](https://code.google.com/p/dynatree/). However, looking at the page and the fiddle , I learned that there is a designated successor named [Fancytree](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/).

I am planning to implement the solution in a production environment.

Which is the best library to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of today (nov. 2013) Dynatree is the stable version.

While the core functionality in Fancytree is already pretty stable too, there still may be some changes to the API and markup. I am planning to release Fancytree early next year.

So if you want to be on the save side, use Dynatree.
If you are fine with core functionality, want to help to test and improve this open source  project and are ready to modify your code every now and then: use Fancytree.
(Disclaimer: I am the author of both.)

**Update 2014-05-01**
Today I released v2.0.0

Comment: now is Mar. 2014, so which one is better, faster and more stable?

Comment: Fancytree is already better and faster. It is also pretty stable(tm) for core functionality, i.e. some extensions are not. But those are missing from Dynatree anyway. Concerning stability of the API, there is still some changing going on: see https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 0):

Dynatree is EOL. Last commit was on 19 Aug 2016.

> I will support Dynatree for a while, but no new features will be added.
>   It is recommended to migrate to Fancytree. It's easy: see also the migration hints.

[Src](https://github.com/mar10/dynatree)